# Adding filters to groupby function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

this is my dataset:

```
Day    Player    Score
1        Andy      6
2        Boby      6
3        Andy      4
4        Carl      2
5        Andy      3
```

This is a simplified example, but basically I want to add a new column ('last_pass_date') which looks for the previous index when the 'Player' achieves a score >5.

What I have is:

```
df['last_pass_date'] = df.groupby(['Player'])['Day'].shift(1)
```

but I am unsure on how to add the additional filter of 'Score' > 5. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Output from my solution is [NaN,NaN,'1',NaN,'3'] when ideally it should be [NaN,NaN,'1',NaN,'1'] since row 3 does not satisfy Score > 5.

Comment: Can you show me your expected output ?

Comment: yeah added it into the main post!

Comment: I think you mean `>= 5` instead of `> 5`. If you meant `> 5`, then all your `last_pass_date` would be `NAN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column of `passed`:

```
df['passed'] = df.Day[df.Score > 5]
```

Group by `Player`, shift `passed` and forward fill to carry the last pass date

```
df['last_pass_date'] = df.groupby('Player').passed.apply(lambda x: x.shift().ffill())
```

Produces the following output for me:

```
   Day Player  Score  passed  last_pass_date
0    1   Andy      6     1.0             NaN
1    2   Boby      6     2.0             NaN
2    3   Andy      4     NaN             1.0
3    4   Carl      2     NaN             NaN
4    5   Andy      3     NaN             1.0
```

Comment: Hello, I'm cuirious here..what if there's no repetition of names here, example for bobby, the last_past_date should have a value of "1" as well..

Comment: that did the job! amazing :)

Comment: @Maku, according to the problem definition, `Bobby` at `Day=2` should have `NaN` for `last_pass_date`. However, if `Bobby` is present on a subsequent day, then `last_pass_date` will be `2`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Day": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "Player": ["Andy", "Boby", "Andy", "Carl", "Andy"],
                   "Score": [6, 6, 4, 2, 3],
                   })
df['last_pass_date'] = None
passed_indices = df["Score"] > 5
df.loc[passed_indices, 'last_pass_date'] = df.loc[passed_indices, 'Day']
df['last_pass_date'] = df.groupby("Player")['last_pass_date'].apply(
    lambda group: group.shift().ffill())
print(df)
```

Produces:

```
   Day Player  Score  last_pass_date
0    1   Andy      6             NaN
1    2   Boby      6             NaN
2    3   Andy      4             1.0
3    4   Carl      2             NaN
4    5   Andy      3             1.0
```

The idea is to set last_pass_date to the current date when the player passes, then forward fill that column for each player. The only extra trick required is to shift by 1 before forward filling the column grouped by players (that way you get the pass date on which the player previously passed)